# Openerp - How to change base currency for exchange rates

Tags: odoo

OpenERP uses EUR as the base currency for exchange rates.

Does anyone knows how can I change that to another currency as the base currency for exchange rates?

What I need to do is to have my default currency exchange rate based on USD and not on EUR.

Thank you in advance

Paulo Matos

Comment: if your problem is solved than you may accept the answer, so other user will notified. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

for base currency change **Setting => Configuration => Accounting => Options => Default company currency** this will default for the base company.

In additionally, if you would like to change multiple currency than **Setting => Configuration => Accounting => Features => Allow multi currencies** make it **True**. This will add Currency field in Invoice, you can change directly from their.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Odedra, thank you once again. This is not the case. The problem is that the OpenERP internal operations uses EUR as the default base currency for exchange rates. Imagine that I work with AOA and USD. Any currency exchange I want to use in OpenERP, must always be based on EUR. I have to define a currency rate between AOA and EUR and also a currency rate between USD and EUR. What I need to do is, to add a currency rate between AOA and USD directly and forget EUR. I want to say that 1 USD = xxxx AOA, or at least say that 1 AOA = xxx USD.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose what you see as a currency exchange rates are default rates which comes with openERP 7 installation. Even if you change a default currency to another, they are not updated. If you want an updated currency list based on your currency try using "Currency Rate Update" module. Also this article might help 
http://www.serpentcs.com/serpentcs-currency-operations-in-openerp-7

Comment: No Scientist1642. This is not the case. Imagine you do not want EUR currency on the system at all. How do you define another currency as the base for all exchange rates? By default OpenERP sets EUR as the system defaul base currency for all exchange rates even if you do not use EUR (i.e. all exchange rates are set based on EUR). What I need to do is to change this system default currency for exchange rates.

Comment: Yes, but after you change the default base currency It doesn't automatically updates exchange rates. You have to update it manually, For example you specified(updated) USD and RUB exchange rates relatively to AOA(accounting => miscellaneous=> currencies=>edit USD,RUB) , now what makes you think that USD and  RUB are still calculated based on EUR? Can you give me a specific action to produce an issue?

Comment: Scientist1642, this is exactly the problem. You cannot inform system that an exchange rate (as per your example USD and RUB), are relatively a specific currency (for instance AOA). On each currency installed on the system, you only say that there is an exchange rate, but you cannot say that this exchange rate is based on a specific currency because OpenERP assumes EUR as the base for all currency exchange rates. What I need to do is exactly inform OpenERP that an exchange is based on the A, B or C currency.

Answer (score 0):

pmatos,

I had the same issue as you but I made it work by doing the following:

1. Set your base currency for your company as whatever you want it to be and then enable multi-currency support
2. Edit the exchange rate for your default currency and set it to "1".
3. Edit the exchange rate for any other currencies that you may be trading with, relative to your own currency.

Once this has been done, there should be no relationship back to Euro or any other currency that you don't need or want.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround to a similar issue.

1. Delete USD currency (if any in system) from Accounting=> Miscellaneouse=> Currencies.
2. Modify EUR to USD and replace euro symbol by $

I am using OpenErp V7.